# Removal of Visible Flight Lines in Image Processing

Tags: digital-image-processing, agisoft-photoscan

I am processing MicaSense RedEdge multi spectral imagery in Agisoft Metashape and have some uneven coloration between the flight lines.

I've used "Calibrate Colors" tool and it hasn't seemed to do anything. Is there another way to even out the lighting between the flight lines?

Comment: Maybe your reflectance panels were not recognized by Metashape?  See appendix A here:  https://agisoft.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/31000148780-micasense-rededge-mx-processing-workflow-including-reflectance-calibration-in-agisoft-metashape-pro#Locate-reflectance-panels.%C2%A0

Comment: It did notice my reflectance panels, thank you though!